# In Android, when is a Thread created in a SurfaceView destroyed?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, surfaceview

I'm analyzing the code associated with [James Cho's, "The Beginner's Guide to Android Game Development"](http://jamescho7.com/), and I've run into some confusing logic associated with Threads I was hoping to get help with.  The full source code I am analyzing [can be downloaded](http://jamescho7.com/book/chapter8) if needed.

The specific code I'm looking for help with is shown below.  Note that I have omitted code that is not relevant to the question.

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
  private Thread gameThread;
  public GameView(Context context, int gameWidth, int gameHeight) {
    SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
      @Override
      public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        initGame();
      }
      @Override
      public void surfaceChanged(omitted) {omitted}
      @Override
      public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        pauseGame();
      }
    });
    private void initGame() {
      gameThread = new Thread(this, "Game Thread");
      gameThread.start();
    }
    private void pauseGame() {
      while (gameThread.isAlive()) {
        try {
          gameThread.join(); 
          break;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The way I read this code, the following relevant logic takes place:

1. When the app is first started and the `GameView` is displayed, a new Thread object is created and associated with our `gameThread` variable.
2. The `gameThread` is given a name and then `start()`ed.
3. If the app loses focus / is paused, and the `gameThread` is running, the `gameThread` is paused via the `join()` method. * note i'm a bit foggy around this logic*
4. If the app regains focus / is restarted, a new Thread is created and assigned to our `gameThread` variable.

My initial reaction to reading this logic is, "Why are we creating a new Thread and assigning it to `gameThread`?  Shouldn't the prior created Thread still exist?"  I did some debugging / logging and discovered at some point between the game being paused and restarted, the `gameThread` Thread is 'destroyed', because if I try a `.getName()` call against `gameThread` during `initGame()` prior to the new Thread being created and assigned, I get a null pointer exception.  If the existing `gameThread` is being destroyed between pause and resume, wouldn't that wipe out any game state associated with that thread?

Can someone walk me through what happens to the Thread as the app loses focused and then regains it (or point me to a resource that does)?

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a good idea to pause or stop threads in `onPause()` so that they don't continue to run while the application is stopped or in a different Activity. This example is relying on `surfaceDestroyed()` to pause the game, which is insufficient, because the surface may not be destroyed if the user taps the power button to blank the display.  (Note I haven't looked beyond what you've posted, so I have no idea if the original code is doing other things in `onPause()` -- if it's pausing the thread activity then it's just fine.)

The interaction between SurfaceView and the Activity lifecycle is covered in some detail in [this article](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity).  Some familiarity with the [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) is assumed.

The `pauseGame()` method you included is calling `Thread.join()`, which waits until the target thread exits.  (It could bail early with an exception, which is likely why it's wrapped in a "while" loop.)  So by the time `pauseGame()` returns, it's guaranteed that the other thread is no longer running.  Some other bit of code that you didn't include must be asking the thread to stop.